# whats wrong with this code i don`t know can anyone help me out:

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

It is a password validation Java Script. I am getting an error everytime i am running (isPasswordValid('Ggtrt54r$')) function. 
I gave UpperCase, LowerCase, 8 characters and Special Characters as isPasswordValid input. But everytime i am getting "('Password Invalid needs Special Characters')" ERROR. My code is not able to pass the last requirenment. can anyone please check and let me know whats wrong i am doing here.

Starts from here

//main function

```
function isPasswordValid(input){

    if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) &&   isLongEnough(input) && hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
        console.log('Code works fine !!');
    } else if (!hasUpperCase(input)) {
             console.log('Password Invalid Needs Uppercase');
    }else if (!hasLowerCase(input)) {
             console.log('Password Invalid needs lowercase');
    } else if (!isLongEnough(input)) {
        console.log('Password Invalid needs 8 Characters');
    } else if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
             console.log('Password Invalid needs Special Characters');
    }
}


    function hasUpperCase (input){
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()){
          return true;
        } 
      }
    }

    function hasLowerCase(input){
      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (input[i] === input[i].toLowerCase()){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    function isLongEnough(input){
      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (input.length === 8){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    function hasSpecialCharacter(input){
      var specialCharacters = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'];
      for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++){

        }
        if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    isPasswordValid('Ggtrt54r$');
```

**$** is the spacial character here but everytime its giving me error need special character . can anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for(var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++){
>
> }
> if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]){
>   return true;
> }
> ```

I think you meant:

```
for(var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++){
  if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yap thanks man . i should be more carefull about all this mistake ... its killing my time a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :  **2 bugs**

> Its match above `8` char so use with
>
> ```
>  if (input.length >= 8){
> ```
>
> And for loop is problem .You are apply the condition after the loop.So
>   change with inside the loop like this
>
> ```
> for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
>     for(var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++){
>     if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]){
>       return true;
>     }
>       }
> ```

```js
function isPasswordValid(input){
if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) && isLongEnough(input) && hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
    console.log('Code works fine !!');
}else if(!hasUpperCase(input)){
         console.log('Password Invalid Needs Uppercase');}
  else if(!hasLowerCase(input)){
         console.log('Password Invalid needs lowercase');}
  else if(!isLongEnough(input)){

    console.log('Password Invalid needs 8 Characters');
  }else if(!hasSpecialCharacter(input)){
         console.log('Password Invalid needs Special Characters');}


}


function hasUpperCase (input){
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()){
      return true;
    } 

  }
}
function hasLowerCase(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] === input[i].toLowerCase()){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
function isLongEnough(input){

  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input.length >= 8){
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input){
  var specialCharacters = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'];
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++){
    if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]){
      return true;
    }
      }
  }
}
isPasswordValid('Ggtrt54r$');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and solution